# IE6 transparent background color not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer, browser

I have looked every where but I can't get IE6 to display a transparent background. Ideally I dont want to use a plugin or .htc.

I have read a few articles that suggest this show work, but it doesn't

```
#example1 {
        background-color: #000;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 1000px;
        height: 1000px;
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=30);
        opacity: 0.3;
        -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That filter is trying to make the entire image 70% transparent, not just the background.

The best thing to do really, is fallback on a behaviour to fix it -- try [IE PNG Fix](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/). You can load the CSS that applies the fix with [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so that it only is applied to IE6.